# UWP app trying to load a local html file to webview control

Tags: c#, webview, uwp

My universal windows app requires to load a html file using webview control. I tried the following solution given in this question. I couldn't make it work.

[Load local html file in WebView Metro Style app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10684741/load-local-html-file-in-webview-metro-style-app)

Now my code is given below. It gives me an error as follows

> Error CS4036  'IAsyncOperation' does not contain a
>   definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'IAsyncOperation'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive for
>   'System'?)    ReaderX c:\users\sumod\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\ReaderX\ReaderX\Views\TextView.xaml.cs  28

This is my code

```
namespace ReaderX.Views
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class TextView : Page
    {
        private NavPoints point;
        public TextView()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            point = (NavPoints)e.Parameter;
            StorageFolder storageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
            StorageFile sampleFile = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync("sample.txt");
            var html = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(sampleFile);

            HTMLViewer.NavigateToString(html);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Do you have "using System;" in the cs file where you declared this class? Most probably it's missing (as the compiler error says), because this should compile...

Comment: @gregkalapos : Yes I have. I have checked it.

Comment: Can you share a repro project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hey if you have time tell me if this works:

Create an Html file in your Assets folder called MyHTMLPage, it has a build action of type content and a Copy to Output to Copy Always.

Html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="background-color: chartreuse">HELLO WORLD, from a webview</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

On Main Page.xaml:

```
  <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <WebView x:Name="MyWebView"  Width="200" Height="300"></WebView>
    </Grid>
```

On Main Page.cs:

```
 public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
        }

        private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string src = "ms-appx-web:///Assets/MyHTMLPage.html";
            this.MyWebView.Navigate(new Uri(src));
        }
    }
```

does this work for you?

Answer (score 0):

The code sample works for me. Did you try with new project? I am sure there is problem with your references.

Try to delete your references one by one to find the culprit.

Comment: I even tried reinstalling visual studio (created a new project also) If I give this code in this method, Its giving me an error. I moved it to another class and it's working properly.