# Unable to open .html file using WebView control in WindowsUniversal app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10, win-universal-app

As the title states, I am building a Windows Universal app and am attempting to load a .html file that is a part of my app package but I am unable to.

The app pops up a dialog that says I need to find another app in the store to open this ms-appx when it is run.

I have specified .html among my file type declarations and at this point I am out of ideas. What am I missing?

I'll add some additional bits of information:
When specifying the source via the XAML designer the autogenerated property is: `Source="ms-appx:///Assets/MyFile.html"`

I have created a custom ContentDialog control and this is where I am attempting to load my WebView with the .html asset. The interesting thing is that when I modify my Source property to be `ms-appx-web` in a normal XAML Page element this properly displays my file. However when I do the same thing, the ContentDialog still shows nothing.

Not really sure what would cause the discrepancy.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10684741/load-local-html-file-in-webview-metro-style-app

Comment: @MehrzadChehraz Added additional clarification to avoid duplication.

Comment: I tested with a normal ContentDialog control and it [works well](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lvtsi.png). Could you share a simple sample that can reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick sample tell me if this help you:

I have an Html file in my Assets folder called MyHTMLPage, it has a build action of type content and a Copy to Output to Copy Always.
My Html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="background-color: chartreuse">HELLO WORLD, from a webview</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

On my Main Page.xaml:

```
  <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <WebView x:Name="MyWebView"  Width="200" Height="300"></WebView>
    </Grid>
```

On my Main Page.cs:

```
 public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
        }

        private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string src = "ms-appx-web:///Assets/MyHTMLPage.html";
            this.MyWebView.Navigate(new Uri(src));
        }
    }
```

and Voila this should work, you should see something like this:
Its not pretty ^^:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea. How is your HTML-File included in the Project? 
See properties of your File --> Advanced --> Build Actíon.

Is it "Compile", "Content", "Embedded Resource". Try to Play around with that, that was sometimes a Problem in My solutions.

HTH,
Oliver